# Redirect domain.com?query_string=* to domain.com

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I have the following url: `domain.com/?query_string=some_variable`

I need all requests for `domain.com/?query_string=*` to 301 redirect to `domain.com`

I have tried with the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^query_string=$
RewriteRule (.*)  http://domain.com?  [R=301,L]
```

in context:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^query_string=$
RewriteRule (.*)  http://domain.com?  [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep redirect rule before other rule and match `^query_string=` in regex to allow anything after `query_string=`.

You can use these rules:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^query_string= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```